# python matplotlib how to plot 20 or required number unique and different colors not gradient colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot unique colors of required numbers but not gradient colors between two colors.

My code:

```
import random
from colour import Color

clr_list = list(Color("red").range_to(Color("green"),30)

for i in range(0,15):
    randomlist = []
    for j in range(0,5):
        n = random.randint(1,30)
        randomlist.append(n)
    plt.plot(randomlist,color=clr_list[i].rgb,label=i)
plt.legend(loc='center left',fontsize = 8)
plt.show()
```

My present output:

[image]

The above plot makes it hard to distinguish different lines. I would like to plot 15 unique colors possible. How to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list with a lot of colors and take some of them:

```py
import matplotlib._color_data as mcd
palette = list(mcd.XKCD_COLORS.values())[::10]
```

This part `[::10]` is to skip similar colors.